# Multiple selections on filter web part

Tags: 2010, list, web-part, filter

I have a text filter web part on my web part page which is connected to a list. I was trying to figure out if there was a way to pass multiple choices to my list using the filter. For example I am filtering on a column called "Team" and the values include Finance, Accounting, IT, HR, etc. I can only pass once choice at a time, but I would like to filter by at least 2 values at once.

Answer (score -1):

You can use choice filter and In the advance settings of this filter, enable multiple values.